# Mongo Map-Reduce query

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

query:-

```
db.items.mapReduce(function(){emit(this.name,this.price);},function(key,value){return Array.sum(value);},{out:"map_reduce_example"})
```

output:-

```
{
    "result" : "map_reduce_example",
    "timeMillis" : 293,
    "counts" : {
        "input" : 4,
        "emit" : 4,
        "reduce" : 0,
        "output" : 4
    },
    "ok" : 1
}
```

Why it is not printing the sum of the price??

Comment: The output is being sent to a collection via `{out:"map_reduce_example"}`. Try `db.map_reduce_example.find()` to see the results.

Comment: I have checked but it contains document of items,but not their sum(price)

Comment: I try this query also:- db.items.mapReduce(function(){emit(this.name,this.price);},function(key,value){var sum=0;for(var i=0;i<value.length;i++){sum=sum+value;}return sum;},{out:"map_reduce"})

Comment: this one is also not working

Comment: Can you please edit your question to include some example documents.